# SQL query that joins results created by a query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables:
TWMWR and TWMWRemark.  I have two competing criteria so I am trying to run the query separately and then join them.  I am trying to find all the records in TWMWR that meet the following criteria:

```sql
PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TXT_REMARK LIKE '%Essential Equipment: N%'
  AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TP_REMARK = '%CIS%'
```

then I want to take the list of WR (the records) and join that with another table to find the records that meet the following criteria:

```sql
PSWMS.TWMREMARK.ID_OPER       = 'IXM0Q74'
AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TP_REMARK     = 'CLM'
AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TXT_REMARK LIKE '%SOC%'
```

They have to be done separately.  Can anyone help?  I have pasted what I have tried below.  I am using mySql developer.

```sql
SELECT PSWMS.TWMWR.CD_WR,
  PSWMS.TWMWR.TP_JOB,
  PSWMS.TWMWR.TS_OPER_RECORDED,
  PSWMS.TWMWR.ID_CUSTOMER,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TS_REMARK,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.ID_OPER,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TP_REMARK AS TP_REMARK1,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TXT_REMARK
FROM PSWMS.TWMWR
INNER JOIN PSWMS.TWMREMARK
ON PSWMS.TWMWR.CD_WR              = PSWMS.TWMREMARK.CD_WR
WHERE PSWMS.TWMWR.TP_JOB          = 'CLMDPD'
AND PSWMS.TWMWR.TS_OPER_RECORDED >= '21, Oct 2013'
AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.ID_OPER       = 'IXM0Q74'
AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TP_REMARK     = 'CLM'
AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TXT_REMARK LIKE '%SOC%'
GROUP BY PSWMS.TWMWR.CD_WR,
  PSWMS.TWMWR.TP_JOB,
  PSWMS.TWMWR.TS_OPER_RECORDED,
  PSWMS.TWMWR.ID_CUSTOMER,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TS_REMARK,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.ID_OPER,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TP_REMARK,
  PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TXT_REMARK
INNER JOIN
  SELECT PSWMS.TWMWR.CD_WR
  FROM PSWMS.TWMWR
  INNER JOIN PSWMS.TWMREMARK
  ON PSWMS.TWMWR.CD_WR              = PSWMS.TWMREMARK.CD_WR
  WHERE PSWMS.TWMWR.TP_JOB          = 'CLMDPD'
  AND PSWMS.TWMWR.TS_OPER_RECORDED >= '21, Oct 2013'
  AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TXT_REMARK LIKE '%Essential Equipment: N%'
  AND PSWMS.TWMREMARK.TP_REMARK = '%CIS%' AS WR
  ON PSWMS.TWMWR.CD_WR = WR.CD_WR, PSWMS.TWMREMARK.CD_WR = WR.CD_WR
```